# Help identifying a techno (?) song

Tags: identify-this-song, techno

At a young age, I saw a music video for a techno/house song, but I am to still to this day unable to find it.

In the music video, is a car(?) moving though a forest area and a chorus line might be "finding lost treasure" (?). The video ends with a person blowing out smoke from his mouth but it's in reverse motion.

Edit:
Additional details

- I think this song was out early 2000 or 2002.
- The line "For the first time, ...Finding lost treasure(?)" was sung but a female singer in the music video
- The female singer was in the car while it was moving through the forest in the music video
- There are cut backs to the female singer simply standing on the road and singing

Comment: Do you remember what year you saw it? Other identifying features of the video? Do you know if the group were American, or from a European country? Any other details?

Comment: I think its early 2000 or 2002, I'm not sure of the band/artist was European or American, And of any other details, I remember the the line "For the first time, ...Finding lost treasure(?)" was sung but a female in the video, she was in the car while it was moving through the forest time, there are cut backs to the female artist simply standing on the road and singing...Hope it helps!

Comment: Best to [edit](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/posts/7167/edit) those details (and any new details you remember) into the question post to maximize responsiveness. Good luck finding the song!

Comment: Added the details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gabriel & Dresden "Tracking Treasure Down"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0BFfeCFsg0